Getting nested response from self related model
I am using fastapi for the first time, and I divided my project into two parts which are admin (used django) and api (fastapi). First I defined my models in django and migrated, and connect fastapi to the existing db.
models.py
class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = "category"

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=True))
    updated_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=True))
    icon = Column(String(100))
    order = Column(Integer)
    lft = Column(Integer)
    rght = Column(Integer)
    tree_id = Column(Integer)
    level = Column(Integer)
    parent_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey("category.id"))

    parent = relationship("Category", remote_side=[id])
    translations = relationship("CategoryTranslation", back_populates="category")


class CategoryTranslation(Base):
    __tablename__ = "category_translation"

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    language_code = Column(String(15))
    name = Column(String(255))
    slug = Column(String(255))
    master_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey("category.id"))

    category = relationship("Category", back_populates="translations")

I'm trying to retrieve nested objects from my database but I'm unsure how to efficiently query and serialize nested objects.
Here's a router:
@router.get("/")
async def get_categories(db: Session = Depends(get_db),):
    data = db.query(categories.Category).options(
          joinedload(categories.Category.translations),
          joinedload(categories.Category.parent)
    ).filter(categories.Category.parent_id.is_(None))
    return data.all()

This returns me ugly response like:
[
  {
    "created_at": "2024-07-16T09:25:24.155984+00:00",
    "order": 0,
    "rght": 4,
    "tree_id": 1,
    "level": 0,
    "parent_id": null,
    "updated_at": "2024-07-16T09:25:39.114618+00:00",
    "id": 1,
    "icon": "",
    "lft": 1,
    "parent": null,
    "translations": [
      {
        "master_id": 1,
        "name": "Design",
        "slug": "design",
        "id": 1,
        "language_code": "uz"
      },
      {
        "master_id": 1,
        "name": "дизайн",
        "slug": "dizain",
        "id": 2,
        "language_code": "ru"
      }
    ]
  }
]

I'd like to get response only with few fields which are name, slug, order, icon, language_code, child
How can I modify my router to achieve this?

You need to create corresponding schema and use it as a response model:
class CategoryTranslationOutpuSchema(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)

    name: str
    slug: str
    language_code: str
    

class CategoryOutputSchema(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)

    order: int
    icon: str
    translations: list[CategoryTranslationOutpuSchema]


@router.get("/", response_model=list[CategoryOutputSchema])
async def get_categories(db: Session = Depends(get_db),):
    data = db.query(categories.Category).options(
          joinedload(categories.Category.translations),
          joinedload(categories.Category.parent)
    ).filter(categories.Category.parent_id.is_(None))
    return data.all()

And, if you need to filter nested data, you can do it this way:
    res = [CategoryOutputSchema.model_validate(category) for category in data]
    for category in res:
        category.translations = [translation for translation in category.translations if translation.language_code == 'en']

    return res

Note: FastAPI will re-validate you response. To avoid second validation you can return JSONResponse directly: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/

Thanks worked, and is it possible to filter them by language using orm or should be done using python code ? Like not getting all translations but just for specific language.

Added the example of how to filter by language_code to my answer
